# SQLSTATE[IM001]: Driver does not support this function: driver does not support that attribute

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel, laravel-5.7

while altering table through migrations gives error,

> SQLSTATE[IM001]: Driver does not support this function: driver does not support that attribute

and this error comes from `$table->string('api_key')->change();` this line has a problem because of that `change()` method.

I am using mssql version = Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-CU9) (KB5000642) - 15.0.4102.2 (X64)
php version = 7.1

```
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class AddTaxesToFeesMasterTable extends Migration
{
 /**
  * Run the migrations.
  *
  * @return void
  */
 public function up()
 {
     Schema::table('api_keys', function (Blueprint $table) {
         $table->string('api_key')->nullable()->change();
     });
 }

 /**
  * Reverse the migrations.
  *
  * @return void
  */
 public function down()
 {
     Schema::table('api_keys', function (Blueprint $table) {
         //
     });
 }
}
```

[image: error]

Comment: "Before modifying a column, you must install the doctrine/dbal package using the Composer package manager. The Doctrine DBAL library is used to determine the current state of the column and to create the SQL queries needed to make the requested changes to your column:"

Comment: If your application is using Microsoft SQL Server, please ensure that you install doctrine/dbal:^3.0.

Comment: @IGP i installed that library still getting same error. when i running same migration on MYSQL it gets migrated but with MSSQL it gives that error.